# A white place from top to the bottom

Tags: html, css

I need help on my Website i am doing for a family member of mine.

[Here is a link to the website](http://www.zitronenfalter-spa.at).
The Issue here is that the white background isn't going from the header to the footer.
The footer should be on the bottom of the website, even if the content is small.

I tried doing height 100% and some other things but it didn't help.

Thank you for your help :) 
I know i have some validating errors which i am going to patch later on.

```
<div id="textfeld">
  <img src="image/viertelkreis.png" id="kreis" />
<h6 class="ubertext">Standort</h6><br /><br />
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d664.691604579604!2d16.37821030367338!3d48.21111491260863!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x476d07a0425e484f%3A0x86fda9d1fb10b5ab!2sLaurenzerberg+5%2C+1010+Wien!5e0!3m2!1sde!2sat!4v1418075117771" width="700" height="500" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>

  <table id="tabelletext1"><tr><td id="besonders">Laurenzerberg 5/12, 1010 Wien</td></tr><tr>
        <td>Ecke Schwedenplatz 2/12</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Telefonnummer</td><td>+43 1 909 34 95</td></tr>
        <tr><td>E-Mail:</td><td> office@zitronenfalter-spa.com</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Inhaberin:</td><td> Ying Qi</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Unternehmensgegenstand:</td><td> Massagendienstleistungen</td></tr></table>

<br />
<br />
  </div>`
```

Comment: Please include the relevant HTML in the question itself, if you want to post a live demo (please do, they're a fantastic means of experimenting with your code) use either [Stack Snippets](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) (here on SO), or a site like [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/). But [don't just link us to your website](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/82548), since as soon as you correct your problem the question becomes meaningless to others in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that, you need to make the `#wrapper` to have a `height:100%` corresponding with `#textfeld` to have a `height:100%`

**For instance,**

You need to make the below css change to achieve what you are looking for.

**The CSS Change:**

```
#wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

#textfeld {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #ffffff;
    border: 2px solid #999;
    height: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 80px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    width: 764px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Hope this helps.

***PS***: You need to remove the footer value of `bottom:0` for the above to work.

Comment: This doesnt helps because the footer is now in the middle of the website

Comment: for that, you need to remove the `bottom:0` to make it work. - @SaVee

Comment: But the site should scale with the content in it.

Comment: It will, but it needs a variable height i.e in percentage. Once that is done as above, it also needs to remove all the positions set i.e bottom/top for it to scale variably. Hope this answers your questions. - @SaVee

Comment: what do you mean with the Positions sets ?

Comment: the one that you had declared, i.e `bottom:0` - @SaVee

Comment: I changed and uploaded it and it doesn't scales

Comment: is that live? Cannot see your change - @SaVee

Comment: can you change the code and comment it. my english isnt good and i dont really know what you mean

Comment: I just checked your page and it works fine now. What is the issue?

Comment: When you zoom the Website in like 120% the footer goes up.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot? As on my end, it's perfectly fine.

Comment: That is because of the other things that you have added to accommodate the Map. Show me the code and I shall let you know where you are making this issue. - @SaVee

Comment: ok .. Got your issue .. Just add `overflow:auto;` to `#textfeld` and it will work fine. This is happening because the map that you have inserted is an iframe code and it is not expanding because it is out of your reach to expand. Just add what I mentioned above and it will work fine. - @SaVee Also if you want, you can upvote my answer.

Comment: Hi @SaVee - I hope you are fine with the things as mentioned above.

Comment: It won't as Map iframe is a dynamically generated code from google. - @SaVee

Answer (score 2):

You have padding on your header div. Take the padding off and you'll be fine.

```
#header {
 padding-top: 10px; 
}
```

Change the height on your image to

```
height: 350px;
```

And that works fine. It was your image that was the problem with your footer.

EDIT:

```
.background-white {
    background: white;
    width: 55%;
    height: 795px;
 }
```

Under your div tag which is:

```
<div align="center" id="wrapper">
```

Add another div called 'background-white' or whatever you wish to call it. Copy the styles above, may need a slight tweak to the height and width if you wish. That should work. Let me know how it looks.

Comment: I dont know how this Helps it just removes the space at the top.

Comment: I've updated my answer further, that should work. Give it a try and let me know. Your header div had 10px padding which was the problem at the top. On the bottom was your image height was to big. If you could copy and paste the html and css code for it, I can help further reposition it.

Comment: Yeah, but my real problem is the white background behind the text i want it to be from the header to the top

Comment: I apologise, if you have a look at my answer i've just updated it. I've kept the last answer for reference. Under edit is what i've done. Try implementing this and let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

remove this style

```
#header {
 padding-top: 10px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can always use min-height on #textfeld and count the value in jQuery.

```
var height = $(window).height() - $('#header').outerHeight() - $('#footer').outerHeight();

$("#textfeld").css({'min-height': height });
```

Comment: I dont really know how to use JQuery. But if u can show me how i can inplement it to the site i would be really happy :)

Comment: You must use jQuery librery: http://jquery.com/download/. I made You an example: http://jsfiddle.net/hgfL0mvo/1/. I remove the positioning absolute from footer.